# Using DataTable with a json

Tags: php, jquery, json, datatables

I'm trying to make a website that can display some data from a mysql database using jquery and i cant figure out how to populate my table with data.
my PHP file looks like this:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$database = "testdatabase";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
// Check connection

if ($conn->connect_error) 
{
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$getinfo = "SELECT * FROM greenhouse";
$names = $conn->query($getinfo);
$str = array(); 
if ($names->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($res = $names->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $str[] = $res;
    }
}

echo json_encode($str);
?>
```

And this is my script:

```
<script>


function get_greenhouses(){
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            //var returnval = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            //document.getElementById("main_text").innerHTML = dataSet[0];
            start_table(JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText));
            //document.getElementById("main_text").innerHTML = returnval[0].Name;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","get_greenhouses.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }

  function start_table(greenhousedata){
    console.log(greenhousedata);
    //document.getElementById("main_text").innerHTML = greenhousedata[0].Adress;
       $('#example1').DataTable( {
        "ajax": greenhousedata,
        columns: [
            { title: "Name" },
            { title: "ID" },
            { title: "plant type" },
            { title: "install date" },
            { title: "adress" }
        ]
    } );
  }
$(function () {
    get_greenhouses();
  });
</script>
```

So i'm trying to have a function get_greenhouses() that starts when the document is loaded. In it i make a request to the PHP file that gets the data, encodes it to json, and sends it back. When i get the data i want to pass it to the start_table() function and then use it to fill the table. Right now i'm getting an error that says:
DataTables warning: table id=example1 - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1
but when i follow the link and check what data i get from the php file it says json and looks correct as far as i can tell.

Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong or if there is a beter way of doing it?

Comment: I will certainly look into this and help further, but have you considered other options instead of datatables? It may take a stretch to begin with AngularJS, but http://ui-grid.info/ is pretty amazing and will top datatable's performance every time. Datatables was originally designed to convert an HTML table that is already loaded into the DOM. UI-Grid uses angular to only render the HTML necessary as it becomes necessary.

Comment: What does the json look like in the console?

Comment: @MikelBitson Datatables does not have to use pre-rendered html and is quite efficient using array data

Comment: @markpsmith I opened the console in firefox and the network answer looks like this: http://imgur.com/zDkwx6z (it's a bit in swedish, hope that's ok)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the code shown below instead.

Just put correct field names of your `greenhouse` table instead of dummy ones specified by `data` option.

```js
function get_greenhouses(){
   $('#example1').DataTable( {
      ajax: {
         url: "get_greenhouses.php",
         dataSrc: ""
      },
      columns: [
          { data: "name",       title: "Name" },
          { data: "id",         title: "ID" },
          { data: "plant",      title: "Plant type" },
          { data: "dt_install", title: "Install date" },
          { data: "address",    title: "Address" }
      ]
   });
}
```

Comment: Tried this answer aswell and it also works like a charm! going to use this one and scrap the get_greenhouse function. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

The `ajax` option is for passing a url so that the plugin makes the ajax request. In your case you are making that request yourself and passing data directly to the plugin

You can continue with your approach by passing your data to the `data` property of the plugin options . See [example](http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html)

```
$('#example1').DataTable( {
        "data": greenhousedata,
```

Or let the plugin make the request itself instead

Comment: Got it working! I changed it to data and then got this error http://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/4. After a bit of googling/trying i got it working by telling it what part of the input data it needed to take for each column. so for example : { title: "Name", "data": "Name" }.

Answer (score 0):

I tried charlietfls solution first and got another error but after 15 min of googling and trying i found out i hade to say what column should use what part of the data, so instead of just having { title: "Name" }, i had to use { title: "Name", "data": "Name" } and after that it worked like a charm.

After that i read Gyrocode.coms answer and tried that aswell and it also worked like a charm if i changed the data: fields to match my incomming data. since this solution let me scrap the get_greenhouses function i chose it instead.

Thanks everyone for the help :)